# Docker image starts fine with docker run but fails with docker-compose with "executable file not found in $PATH: unknown" error

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to deploy Caddy proxy with Librespeed Speedtest app.

I'm building a docker image locally with
`docker build -t app .` the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

# Install extensions
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

# Prepare files and folders

RUN mkdir -p /speedtest/

# Copy sources

COPY backend/ /speedtest/backend

COPY results/*.php /speedtest/results/
COPY results/*.ttf /speedtest/results/

COPY *.js /speedtest/
COPY favicon.ico /speedtest/

COPY docker/servers.json /servers.json

COPY docker/*.php /speedtest/
COPY docker/entrypoint.sh /

# Prepare environment variables defaults

ENV TITLE=LibreSpeed
ENV MODE=standalone
ENV PASSWORD=password
ENV TELEMETRY=false
ENV ENABLE_ID_OBFUSCATION=false
ENV REDACT_IP_ADDRESSES=false
ENV WEBPORT=80

# Final touches

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["bash", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

This Dockerfile builds file structure and runs the following script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -x

# Cleanup
rm -rf /var/www/html/*

# Copy frontend files
cp /speedtest/*.js /var/www/html/

# Copy favicon
cp /speedtest/favicon.ico /var/www/html/

# Set up backend side for standlone modes
if [ "$MODE" == "standalone" ]; then
  cp -r /speedtest/backend/ /var/www/html/backend
  if [ ! -z "$IPINFO_APIKEY" ]; then
    sed -i s/\$IPINFO_APIKEY\ =\ \'\'/\$IPINFO_APIKEY\ =\ \'$IPINFO_APIKEY\'/g /var/www/html/backend/getIP_ipInfo_apikey.php
  fi
fi

if [ "$MODE" == "backend" ]; then
  cp -r /speedtest/backend/* /var/www/html
  if [ ! -z "$IPINFO_APIKEY" ]; then
    sed -i s/\$IPINFO_APIKEY\ =\ \'\'/\$IPINFO_APIKEY\ =\ \'$IPINFO_APIKEY\'/g /var/www/html/getIP_ipInfo_apikey.php
  fi
fi

# Set up index.php for frontend-only or standalone modes
if [ "$MODE" == "frontend" ]; then
  cp /speedtest/frontend.php /var/www/html/index.php
elif [ "$MODE" == "standalone" ]; then
  cp /speedtest/standalone.php /var/www/html/index.php
fi

# Apply Telemetry settings when running in standalone or frontend mode and telemetry is enabled
if [[ "$TELEMETRY" == "true" && ( "$MODE" == "frontend" || "$MODE" == "standalone" ) ]]; then
  cp -r /speedtest/results /var/www/html/results

  sed -i s/\$db_type\ =\ \'.*\'/\$db_type\ =\ \'sqlite\'\/g /var/www/html/results/telemetry_settings.php
  sed -i s/\$Sqlite_db_file\ =\ \'.*\'/\$Sqlite_db_file=\'\\\/database\\\/db.sql\'/g /var/www/html/results/telemetry_settings.php
  sed -i s/\$stats_password\ =\ \'.*\'/\$stats_password\ =\ \'$PASSWORD\'/g /var/www/html/results/telemetry_settings.php

  if [ "$ENABLE_ID_OBFUSCATION" == "true" ]; then
    sed -i s/\$enable_id_obfuscation\ =\ .*\;/\$enable_id_obfuscation\ =\ true\;/g /var/www/html/results/telemetry_settings.php
  fi

  if [ "$REDACT_IP_ADDRESSES" == "true" ]; then
    sed -i s/\$redact_ip_addresses\ =\ .*\;/\$redact_ip_addresses\ =\ true\;/g /var/www/html/results/telemetry_settings.php
  fi

  mkdir -p /database/
  chown www-data /database/
fi

chown -R www-data /var/www/html/*

# Allow selection of Apache port for network_mode: host
if [ "$WEBPORT" != "80" ]; then
  sed -i "s/^Listen 80\$/Listen $WEBPORT/g" /etc/apache2/ports.conf
  sed -i "s/*:80>/*:$WEBPORT>/g" /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf 
fi

echo "Done, Starting APACHE"

# This runs apache
apache2-foreground
```

Then I just run it with
`docker run -d -p '2015:80' app`

And everything works perfect.

But when I'm trying to run that image with following docker-compose

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  caddy:
    image: caddy:2.3.0-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - $PWD/Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile
      - caddy_data:/data
      - caddy_config:/config
  app:
    image: app
    ports:
      - 2015:80
    restart: unless-stopped
    #command: "bash /entrypoint.sh"
volumes:
  caddy_data:
  caddy_config:
```

I'm getting the following error:

> $ docker-compose -f app.compose.yml run caddy app
>
> Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "app": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

As you can see by commented-out command section, I tried to call `entrypoint.sh` manually as a string and as a `["bash", "/entrypoint.sh"]`. But nothings has changed.

It looks like I'm missing something about difference between running images with docker-compose and docker. But what exactly?

Comment: Please don't link to offsite resources like this. If they change the question may become unhelpful to future users. Can you post the current contents in your question please?

Comment: Much better, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong command.
`docker-compose run` is similiar to `docker exec`.
You want `docker-compose -f app.compose.yml up -d` to run it in the background or `docker-compose -f app.compose.yml up` to run it in the foreground (similiar to `-ti` in `docker run`)